# mesos http api does not work as supposed to

Tags: mesos

I am trying to use HTTP API of Mesos. 
I have tried to subscribe to already running framework with the following command, but it creates another framework instead of subscribing to existing one. Also, the response does not include mesos-stream-id, therefore I cannot execute another command like teardown on the framework that was created with the subscribe request.

this is the command I use to subscribe to an existing framework.

```
curl -H "Host: 149.xxx.xxx.xx:5050" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Connection: close" -X POST \
-d '{"type": "SUBSCRIBE","subscribe" : {"framework_info" :{"user" : "foo","name": "test", "framework_id": {"value" : "ab9cbd17-d7a4-4889-af39-1b372d16cf51-0000"}}, "force": true}}' \
149.xxx.xxx.xx:5050/api/v1/scheduler/
```

the response to the command above is;

> 423
>   {"type":"SUBSCRIBED","subscribed":{"framework_id":{"value":"b3a72ba7-e233-45cb-92c5-bd98780e5517-0001"},"heartbeat_interval_seconds":15.0,"master_info":{"id":"b3a72ba7-e233-45cb-92c5-bd98780e5517","ip":1368827285,"port":5050,"pid":"master@149.xxx.xxx.xx:5050","hostname":"149.xxx.xxx.xx","version":"1.6.0","address":{"hostname":"149.xxx.xxx.xx","ip":"149.xxx.xxx.xx","port":5050},"capabilities":[{"type":"AGENT_UPDATE"}]}}}20
>   {"type":"HEARTBEAT"}20 {"type":"HEARTBEAT"}20

as you can see the response has different framework id and does not include  mesos-stream-id. I can see from the web panel that this new framework was actually created.

Any ideas?,
thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you try to resubscribe after a disconnect? If so, is the framework ID you provide in the `SUBSCRIBE` message the same that was assigned to the scheduler during initial subscription?

Comment: I am running a framework through java my java code. While this framework is  running, I would like to kill a task or teardown the whole framework over a terminal using HTTP API.  It asks for mesos-stream-id, which I do not have. I thought that if I subscribe to framework(I see its id over mesos web panel), it would return a stream id. Then I can use it to kill a task or tearing down the framework. Am I missing a point here.

Comment: Maybe you confuse framework and operator HTTP APIs? It sounds to me that you try to tamper with the connection between the framework and Mesos master, and I'm glad you're failing. If you want to teardown a framework, look at http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/teardown/ . If you want to kill a task, look into UI or CLI of your framework.

Comment: Thanks rukletsov. I would be really glad if you could tell me what to do for the following situation;
I am running a job consists of tasks running in docker containers on agents. One of these tasks is the job master, which decides when to kill the framework or kill few of the tasks or add new tasks to the job. I can kill the framework using the endpoint you have mentioned. What should I do in order to add or kill tasks. As I mentioned one of the tasks(job master) will decide on this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you confuse the [operator](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operator-http-api/) and the [framework (aka scheduler)](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/scheduler-http-api/) API. As an operator, you cannot impersonate a framework and kill its tasks on its behalf. As an operator, there is no easy way to kill arbitrary tasks, see [MESOS-3220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3220).

What you can do instead, is to ask the framework you use to kill a specific task. Most general-purpose Mesos frameworks, like [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/), can do this (FYI, the use the aforementioned scheduler API to relay the kill request to Mesos).